# When the second time using JQuery ajax to get local .HTML content, the js of the index.html is invalid

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I am sorry for my poor English...

Now I doing phonegap development.
I want to use JQuery ajax to get local .HTML content and insert this content into the div by id="next-page" in index.html.  And the first time I click the btn  it's everything OK.But when
the second time I click the btn,It can be jump to page, but the class of the query listview、li is missing. I think it's the jquery.js and jquery-mobile.js invalid.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<title>demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile-1.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!--home page:schedule-->
<div data-role="page" id="schedule">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"></div>

<div id="wrapper1">
    <div id="scroller">
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" class="ulspan">
                <li><a id="first-btn">Carrier<span></span></a></li>
            </ul> 
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="next-page">

</div>
```

This is my other.html

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <a onClick="showCarrier()" data-corners="false" class="navbar-btn back-btn" style="border-radius:5px;left:18px;" data-rel="back">Back</a>

</div>
<div id="wrapper2">
    <div id="scroller">
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="carrier" data-theme="d">
               <li><a><span>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span></a></li>
               <li><a><span>BBBBBBBBBBBB</span></a></li>
               <li><a><span>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span></a></li>
               <li><a><span>BBBBBBBBBBBB</span></a></li>
               <li><a><span>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Response method when "first-btn" click.

```
$.ajax({
           url:"carrier.html",
           async:true,
           type:'Get',
           dataType:'html',
           timeout:5000,
           error:function(data){showAlert('Error loading data')},
           success:function(data){
           console.log(data);
           $("#next-page").html(data);
           $.mobile.changePage($("#next-page"),{transition:"slide"});
   })
```

Comment: I haven't used jQuery mobile yet but I think you don't have to load the page by ajax **and** $.mobile.changePage?

Comment: Thanks for your respond.Can you tell me how do you done??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand correctly.  Are you saying the second time you click the button, the content of the AJAX call shows up on the page, but it is not formatted correctly?

If that is the case, it is probably because you need to call

```
$('#carrier').listview('refresh');
```

after injecting a new listview ul dynamically.

That being said, there are other issues with your approach, but the above should fix your immediate issue.

Comment: Thanks Steve!I try your suggest but no effect.When the second time I click the btn,It can be jump to page,but the css of the list view is invalid,I found the Tag's class is missing in the brower debug tool(class="ui-listview".........).So I think is the JQuery.js or JQuery-mobile.js invalid.